why does thread_local variable has different influence on std::array and my customed class?
I'm trying to optimize my code by moving a member variable of a class to thread_local, but it turns out that things just get worse. I reproduced it with the following code:
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

void bind_core(int cpu_core) {
  cpu_set_t cpuset;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
  CPU_SET(cpu_core, &cpuset);
  if (0 != pthread_setaffinity_np(pthread_self(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset)) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to set CPU affinity");
  }
}

struct Bench {
private:
  const char *name_;
  size_t repeat_;
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start_;

public:
  Bench(const char *name, size_t repeat)
      : name_(name), repeat_(repeat), start_(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) {
  }
  ~Bench() {
    printf("Bench: %s %luns\n", name_,
           (std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start_).count() / repeat_);
  }
  template <typename Func> void operator()(Func &&f) const {
    for (size_t i{}; i < repeat_; i++) {
      f(i);
    }
  }
};

inline uint64_t random64() {
  static std::random_device rd;
  static std::default_random_engine re{rd()};
  static std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t> distribution;
  return distribution(re);
}

/// \todo async
inline void generate_random_data(void *buf, size_t len, uint n_thread = 1) {
  if (!n_thread)
    throw std::invalid_argument("invalid argument n_thread: 0");

  std::atomic_uint todo = n_thread;
  std::vector<std::thread> thrds;
  for (int i = 0; i < n_thread; ++i) {
    size_t step = len / n_thread;
    assert(!(step % 8));
    thrds.emplace_back([=, &todo] {
      uint64_t *tmp = (uint64_t *)((char *)(buf) + i * step);
      uint64_t *upper = (uint64_t *)((char *)(buf) + (i + 1) * step);
      for (; tmp < upper; ++tmp) {
        auto v = random64();
        memcpy(tmp, &v, sizeof v);
      }
      todo--;
    });
  }
  for (auto &th : thrds) {
    th.join();
  }
}
std::array<std::array<char, 4096>, 65536> random_data;
template <typename T> inline void doNotOptimize(T &&value) {
  asm volatile("" : "+m,r"(value) : : "memory");
}

constexpr auto buf_size = 4000;
constexpr auto copy_size = 4000;
constexpr auto repeat = 10'000'000;

template <size_t SIZE> struct Buffer {
  std::array<char, SIZE> buf;
  char *ptr;
  Buffer() : ptr(buf.data()) {}

  constexpr auto size() const { return SIZE; }
  char *data() { return ptr; }
  void append(const char *data, size_t size) {
    memcpy(buf.data(), data, copy_size);
  }
};

struct TestArr {
  std::array<char, buf_size> buf;
  char padding[4096 - buf_size];

  void run(size_t i) {
    doNotOptimize(memcpy(&buf[0], random_data[i & 65535].data(), copy_size));
  }
};

struct TestArrTL {
  static thread_local std::array<char, buf_size> buf;
  char *p = buf.data();

  void run(size_t i) {
    doNotOptimize(memcpy(&buf[0], random_data[i & 65535].data(), copy_size));
    doNotOptimize(p += copy_size);
  }
};
thread_local std::array<char, buf_size> TestArrTL::buf;

struct TestBuf {
  Buffer<buf_size> buf;
  void run(size_t i) {
    doNotOptimize(memcpy(buf.data(), random_data[i & 65535].data(), copy_size));
  }
};
struct TestBufTL {
  static thread_local Buffer<buf_size> buf;
  void run(size_t i) {
    doNotOptimize(memcpy(buf.data(), random_data[i & 65535].data(), copy_size));
  }
};
thread_local Buffer<buf_size> TestBufTL::buf;

int main() {
  generate_random_data(random_data.data(), 4096 * 65536, 8);
  printf("data ready\n");

  std::thread t1([] {
    bind_core(1);
    Bench("TestArr", repeat)([](auto i) { TestArr().run(i); });
  });
  std::thread t2([] {
    bind_core(2);
    Bench("TestArrTL", repeat)([](auto i) { TestArrTL().run(i); });
  });
  std::thread t3([] {
    bind_core(3);
    Bench("TestBuf", repeat)([](auto i) { TestBuf().run(i); });
  });
  std::thread t4([] {
    bind_core(4);
    Bench("TestBufTL", repeat)([](auto i) { TestBufTL().run(i); });
  });
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  t3.join();
  t4.join();
  bind_core(5);
  Bench("TestBufTL_main", repeat)([](auto i) { TestBufTL().run(i); });
}

the output result is:
data ready
Bench: TestBuf 391ns
Bench: TestArrTL 399ns
Bench: TestBufTL 460ns
Bench: TestArr 482ns
Bench: TestBufTL_main 339ns

we can see that the thread_local seems to influenced std::array and Buffer differently. It makes std::array better, while Buffer worse, any reason? My guess is maybe it has something to do with the constructor, since Buffer::Buffer() is not constexpr. but still, I don't see any reason how a constexpr constructor would affect it either.
OS: Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
kernel : 5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
Architecture: x86_64
Compiler: gcc-11.4.0
compile flags: -O3

Using system_clock is wrong, you most likely shouldn't roll your own microbenchmarks. Use google benchmark or some other well-established benchmark library instead.

Also, the OS and kernel is not as important as the compiler and compiler flags.

You suspect it has to do with construction. You can test this theory: Have Bench run at least one iteration, before starting the timing.

@JeffGarrett I re-test it  with warm-up, it turns out no difference
